# Create list of empty lists having name

Tags: python, list, empty-list

I am pretty new to python and looking for how to create a list of empty lists having names more efficiently than presented below

I would like to have some names to the lists.

```
flattenlist_x1 = []
flattenlist_x2 = []
flattenlist_x3 = []
flattenlist_x4 = []
flattenlist_x5 = []
flattenlist_x6 = []
flattenlist_x7 = []
flattenlist_x8 = []
flattenlist_x9 = []
flattenlist_x10 = []
flattenlist_x11 = []
flattenlist_x12 = []

flattenlist_list = [flattenlist_x1, flattenlist_x2, flattenlist_x3, flattenlist_x4,
                    flattenlist_x5, flattenlist_x6, flattenlist_x7, flattenlist_x8,
                    flattenlist_x9, flattenlist_x10, flattenlist_x11, flattenlist_x12]
```

Comment: flattenlist_list = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[]] … then the “names” are flattenlist_list[0], flattenlist_list[1], and so on

Comment: thank you. But is there any way to have custom names instead of grabbing the index from flattenlist_list?

Comment: @OmkarS this is not clear what is your ultimate goal. Culd you give more details ? It is often bad practice to try to have many named lists. It is better/more practical to work with indexes, as you can easily iterate in a loop.

Comment: @Malo I agree with you, I thought it will be better to understand when I pass on the code to someone as newbie as me :D We are not from a programming background. Anyway thanks, I would use the method Jeremy mentioned for my understanding.

Comment: @OmkarS the way you were doing it yield custom names, but as you found out, having a custom name for each member of an array gets impractical for larger arrays.  Use array indexing instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beacuse you want it to have name, how about using dict?

```
flattenlist_list = {}
for i in range(1,13):
    flattenlist_list['flattenlist_x'+str(i)]=[]
print(flattenlist_list)
```